# Hiding scrollbar of NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

Ok, I'm stumped here. I have a few scrollable views in my window, two NSTableViews, and an NSTextView.  I'd like to have the scrollbar to hide when not in use, and used the setting of the NSScrollView in IB in Xcode to do so. For the NSTextView it works, but for the NSTableViews the scrollbar won't hide, and the scrollbars are also much wider.

The scrollbar settings are exactly the same for all three NSScrollViews.

What am I missing here, is there another secret setting?

(Lion, Xcode 4)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `NSScrollView` was overlapping a few pixels with a view next to it. I moved them a bit in Interface Builder and it all works fine now.

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me for soooo long! Just adding a line next to the scroll view will trigger this.